# How to know how many tasks are already completed?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

In C++ Builder 10.3.3 I'm using the following test code:

```
int count = 500;
 _di_ITask* task = new _di_ITask[count];
ProgressBar1->Position = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    task[i] = TTask::Create([i, this](){
        // do something...
        Sleep(10);
    });
    task[i]->Start();
    //ProgressBar1->Position = numberOfFinishedTasks;
    //Application->ProcessMessages();
}
TTask::WaitForAll(task, count - 1);
```

In this case there are 500 test tasks and I would like my ProgressBar component to show the current number of completed tasks. I don't know how to get that info. Thanks!

Comment: Increment an atomic counter at the end of each task?

Comment: @AlanBirtles The problem is how to get that info.

Comment: @Tracer Each task will have to "report" that i's finished, e.g. increment a atomic counter. (and then trigger repainting or so)

Comment: @churill I don't know how to detect when each of the tasks is finished. Ideally, something like OnTaskFinished event would solve the trick, but I cannot find it.

Comment: But ... you create those task yourself. Can't you insert it after `Sleep(10)`?

Comment: @churill Yes, I tried that. I incremented the counter in critical section and updated the progressbar inside a TTimer. But, UI is frozen until all tasks are completed.

Comment: Instead of updating `TProgressBar` within long cycle and using `Sleep()` it is better to make *all operations (your tasks)* using [TThread class](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread). And what `TTask` is? Class? Record?

Comment: @Dima [`TTask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) is part of Embarcadero's [Parallel Programming Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have the lambda itself update the ProgressBar before exiting. You can use [`TThread::Synchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [`TThread::Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) for that.

The problem is, [`TTask::WaitForAll()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask.WaitForAll) is a blocking method that does not pump the main UI message queue at all, so `Synchronize()`/`Queue()` requests will not be processed at all. You can get around that by calling `WaitForAll()` in a loop with a timeout so that the loop can pump messages as needed.

Try something like this:

```cpp
int count = 500;
std::vector<_di_ITask> task(count);

ProgressBar1->Position = 0;
ProgressBar1->Min = 0;
ProgressBar1->Max = count;
ProgressBar1->Step = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    task[i] = TTask::Create(
        [i, this](){
            // do something...
            TThread::Queue(nullptr, ProgressBar1->StepIt);
        }
    );
    task[i]->Start();
}

while (!TTask::WaitForAll(task.data(), count - 1, 1000)){
    Application->ProcessMessages();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! You are a real savior Remy :) Thanks.

Comment: A similar approach explained in detail in a youtube video: "C++ Builder - Parallel Library vs. TThread" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTf7m1jVcbY